Does using food as an analogy reduce the impact of scenes of horror/violence?
I'm working on a story where a vampire hunter is using a powerful pistol against a vampire and I'm wondering if my description reduces the effect. I wanted it to be gross and leave an impression to the reader about the hunter's victory over his prey. My example of this from what I've written is:

The hands of the hidden gunman fanned the hammer of his revolver, sending four more shots through Khorne's body, leaving it looking like a block of swiss cheese covered in and dripping with thick, chunky chili.


An analogy can work, just not yours - not if it is supposed to convey horror or domination.

leaving it looking like a block of swiss cheese covered in and dripping with thick, chunky chili.

That reads like a screen play for a Tom and Jerry slapstick cartoon.  It is also overly wordy and clumsy.

leaving it looking like a block of swiss cheese dripping with chunky chili.

David Drake effectively used a comparison to food in the novel Rolling Hot in a scene describing the destruction of several tanks:

Ransom centered her projection sight on a tank's back deck, just behind the turret ring.  The target's slope gave her a perfect shot.  Cyan bolts streamed through the holographic image of her sight, splashing huge craters in thin armor dessigned only to stop shell splinters.
In gunnery simulators, the screaming tank crew didn't try to abandon their vehicle a second or two after it was too late.  Ransom's bolts punched into the interior of the tank.  A blast of foul white smoke erupted from the turret hatches and the cavity ripped by the tribarrel.
The tank commander and the naked torso of his gunner flew several meters in the air.  The tank began to burn sluggishly.
Jane Ransom's hands swung for another target, but there were no targets remaining here.
The tanks's thickest armor was frontal.  Striking from above and behind, the tribarrels ripped them as easily as so many cans of sardines.
Cans of barbequed pork.  The gunnery simulators didn't provide the odor of close action, either.

The bodies of the dead tank crews are burning inside the wrecked vehicles.  Drake ties a smell known to his readers (meat on a barbeque grill) to the smell of death, demeaning the dead by equating them to pork (pig meat) to drive home the horror of the scene.
Note that the analogy itself is short and brutal, to convey the brutality of the scene.


The hands of the hidden gunman fanned the hammer of his revolver.  Four shots rang out, shredding Khorne's chest like a side of beef in a log chipper.

Probably not all that good.  I'm no author.

"Probably not all that good" - I found it quite effective. Keeps the general idea of the analogy in mind but also clearly illustrates what's happening, powerful imagery. Makes me feel like I wouldn't want to be on the wrong end of that revolver. +1

Whether the food analogy reduces the impact of your horror scene depends on what kind of impact you aim for. The food analogy turns your scene humoristic, so if that is the impact you want, then no, it does not reduce but generate the humor. But if you aim for horror, then yes, the humorous food analogy reduces the dread and terror.
If you want to increase horror, do not use analogies at all. Analogies dilute all emotional effects.

You can do it. But why would blood be chunky like chili? Fanned the hammer? I had to look up the phrase. I would be more plain. You clearly are trying to be too fancy. Nobody wants crypticism. Fancy doesn't mean descriptive. You are supposed to SHOW, not flaunt. You're not a peacock trying to find a mate.

The hands of the hidden gunman rapidly pulled on the hammer of his revolver, sending four more shots through Khorne's body, leaving it resembling a ravaged wheel of gouda, its surface cratered and oozing a viscous, crimson marinara.

Gouda/Swisscheese and marinara/salsa/chili? It sounds like you're trying to evoke a laugh. You want to write so that the reader is horrified, right?
You need to make the words deceive the reader's ears and eyes. You want them to believe they themselves saw and heard the bullets enter.

The hidden gunman's finger rapidly pulled back on the trigger; ONCE! TWICE! THREE TIMES! FOUR TIMES MORE!- unleashing a stuttering, explosive burst of gunfire that ripped through Khorne's body with a rapid succession of wet, meaty slaps. The shots tore through the undead's skin and muscle, shredding the monster's organs and splintering bone, the sound of each impact like a butcher's cleaver biting deep into a carcass. The gunman's revolver spat out its last round, the final shot a deafening, eardrum-shattering crash that left the air ringing with the echoes of violence.


You don't "pull the hammer." You pull the trigger.  On a revolver, pulling the trigger causes the hammer to fire a shot.  You can pull the hammer on a revolver back and release it to fire a shot, but you wouldn't say you pulled the hammer.  "Fanning the hammer" is a known expression for a specific way of rapidly firing shots from a revolver.  You need to know about the things your characters use and do in your stories.
